# Why are there few answers on homework-and-exercise questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, tags, homework-and-exercises

I actually asked a question with the [homework-and-exercises](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework-and-exercises) tag. Then, I was searching [some question with the tag](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework-and-exercises). I had visited 50 pages. Most of the questions don't have answers. And, most of the questions have a low number of views. But, why don't people come to answer those questions when they see the [homework-and-exercises](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework-and-exercises) tag?

There are a lot of physicists either. But, no one comes to answer those questions. What's the reason of it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many instances of homework questions getting answers before they are closed. But in those cases where they do not get answers...

Many posts that fall under the "homework-and-exercise" tag do not follow the site policy on homework-like questions. Instead of asking about physics concepts in the context of an exercise problem, they are just looking for a solution, how to obtain the result of a specific calculation, etc. Therefore, they get closed, or at the very least users know not to answer questions that should be closed.

Comment: I want to know why [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/632828/calculating-frequency-of-oscillation) was closed. I had solved the problem later.. And, I showed some work what I tried. My solution in that post was completely closed to the accurate answer. Although why it was closed?

Comment: @Istiak A question asking “What am I missing?” is not a conceptual question; it is an off-topic check-my-work question. Furthermore, that question doesn’t make sense because what you state is the correct answer doesn’t even have the right dimensions to be a frequency. Are you stating just the correct numerical prefactor in front of the square root? If so, you need to say so.

Comment: @G.Smith So, how the question should be? I was doing wrong with equation. I misunderstood. I was directly doing addition rather than vector addition. While both of them were vector. I had to do vector addition. But, I didn't know that(Literally you can say I forgot). Where can I read about on-topic of homework-and-exercise's question?